# How to get sum of multiples of 5

Tags: r

> Create a function that only shows the sum of whole numbers that are
> also multiples of 5 that are between the range 1,n.

So far, I got to the point where the function shows me the values that meet the above mentioned criteria, but all I gut are the Boolean values. Not sure of to change them to values so I can get the sum.

This is what I have:

```
sumnumbers <- function(n) {
  multiples.5 <- c(1:n)
  return(multiples.5 %% 5== 0)
}  
  
sumnumbers (n = 15)
```

And this is what I get:

> [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

On the other hand, if I change the code and add the sum to the function, I only get the number of instances where the criteria is met. Example:

```
sumanumbers <- function(n) {
  multiples.5 <- c(1:n)
  return(sum(multiples.5 %% 5== 0))
}  
  
sumatoria (n = 15)
```

I get 3 when n = 15.

Comment: Do you need `multiples.5 <- c(1:n); i1 <- multiples.5 %% 5== 0; return(sum(multiples.5[i1]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sumnumbers <- function(n) {
  multiples.5 <- c(1:n)
  return(sum(multiples.5[multiples.5 %% 5== 0]))
}  

sumnumbers (n = 15)
```

`multiples.5 %% 5== 0`  will give you a logical vector of True False. You can use it to identify the locations of the multiples of 5 in `c(1,n)`. Thus, `multiples.5[multiples.5 %% 5== 0]` will extract only the numbers that are multiples of 5 so you can sum them up.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Will give it a try and see how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
sumnumbers <- function(n) sum(seq(0, n, 5))
```

or

```
sumanumbers <- function(n) sum(which(seq(n) %% 5 == 0))
```